# chmod with group inheritance rights rwx for user & group only

Tags: python, linux, chmod

In order to create a shared folder for a given group of users, I need restricted directory rights with inheritance.
The goal is that only root and users members to the specified group can read & wright inside, by inheritating these rights for future content in my directory. Something like:

```
drwxrws--- 2 root terminator  6 28 mai   11:15 test
```

I am able to obtain this with 2 calls of chmod:

```
chgrp terminator test

chmod 770 test
chmod g+s
```

It would be nice to do this in one command using a numeric mask. I need to use a mask, because it is a python script who is supposed to do the job using os.chmod(). Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `chmod u+rwx,g+rws,o-rwx test` do what you want?

Comment: It seems to do this. I'l like to construct the respectif mask in order to make this call from a python script with os.chmod() who accepts only numeric masks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.chmod` does exactly the same as the `chmod` utility, but you need to remember that the argument to `chmod` is a string representing a bitmap in *octal* notation, not decimal. That means the equivalent to

```
chmod 2770 test
```

is

```
os.chmod('test', 0o2770)
```

You probably used `os.chmod('test', 2770)`, which would be `5322` in octal, which is consistent whit the bitmask you seem to get.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod u+rwx,g+rws,o-rwx test` should do what you want.

Alternatively, the following should do it from within a script:

```
import os
import stat
os.chmod('test', stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_ISGID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sticky bit from the command line with one call of the chmod command like so:

```
chmod 2770 test
```

The preceding '2' sets the sticky bit for the group.

os.chmod() appears to need a preceeding zero so that it knows the digits are octal. I've tested the following successfully:

```
import os
os.chmod('test', 02770)
```

Comment: No, it does not do this, I've already tried. I get d-ws-w--wT 2 root terminator    6 28 mai   12:21 test.